# Add a label to a panel or groupbox on button click

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

Is there a way to add a label or content to a panel/groupbox once a button has been clicked ?

[image]

So for instance, lets say I wrote some content in the above textbox and I hit Post button. Is there a way to add this content in the below panel/groupbox ? And if I can't add to a panel/groupbox, which tool should I use ?

Comment: So are you trying to make the Panel below, your Output and the textbox your Input. If that is the case, can you add your current code for the textbox.

Comment: @Juniar I didn't write code for the textbox

Comment: You are suppose to have the code. Where you will indicate that the content should be placed or output it on the Panel. Such that on clicking Post it outputs content to panel.

Comment: @Juniar I'll write the code in the button click section. So once the button is clicked, I want to do what I said above in my question

Comment: Exactly that should be your code.

Comment: @Juniar But how can you do that ? This is the problem I'm trying to figure out. And how can you expand the panel (by adding a scroll bar feature ?) so that it gets bigger the more you add content to it.

Comment: The scroll bar will appear automatically as you add more content. To access the definition or source code, Just double click on the Post button.

Comment: @Juniar Oh ok. And how do u add the content to the panel ? Thats my main question.

Comment: I might have to add this as your answer: When you double Click the Post button add this code and make sure your Textbox is called textBox1: MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Content);

Answer (score 0):

How to Display content from a TextBox when Clicked.

Please check on your MSVC under Solution Properties for all the Buttons, Text and Panels properties. Example; Button1, TextBox1 etc. Then make functions calls and assignments by these reference.

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
 MessageBox.Show(" "+ TextBox1.Text);
```

}

This will display your content to a Pop up window. You can also try TextBox1.Content instead of TextBox1.Text.

NB: This code should be placed on your POST button.

Comment: You still didn't get my point. What I want to do is simply add the contents of the textbox into the panel below when the button is clicked.

Comment: What is the name of the panel. On the POST button add Panel1.Text = " "+ TextBox1.Text; Make sure to confirm the name of the panel on the Properties Menu. Or Panel1.Content = " "+ TextBox1.Text;

Comment: You need to add a Label on it and then since this is a label you will have your code as; label1.Text = (" "+ TextBox1.Text); But you need to add or create a new label for display.